# Command prompt doesn't show any exceptions or errors for grails application

Tags: exception, grails, stack-trace

I have grails application.

If there are any error or exceptions (compile ot run time), then previously cmd prompt shows all errors/exceptions. But from last few days cmd prompt doesn't show any stacktrace.

So I am unable to figure out where is the problem in my code.

Debugging is literally impossible for me.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Check your logging settings in `Config.groovy`.

Comment: log4j configuration from Config.Groovy was commented.

Comment: That would explain it then. (:

Answer (score 0):

log4j configuration from Config.Groovy

```
log4j.main = {
   error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
        'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
        'org.springframework',
        'org.hibernate',
        'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}
```

Config.groovy should have this log4j configuration to enable errors and exceptions to be shown on command prompt.

For detailed logging configuration please check these links [Grails Logging](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#logging) and [Wiki - Grails logging](https://grails.org/version/Logging/1).